# Websocket can't receive data

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have an Angular 4 and Java/Spring MVC / Jhipster website, and I am trying to create a websocket using [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) (which uses sock-js and stomp.js). I can connect to the websocket, but when I try to send data from my Java code to the client, nothing happens. Please help me out.

With the below, I'm just trying to visit http://localhost:9001/api/websocket/testSend in my browser, and watch it send data to any clients subscribed to the `/topic/messages`.

```
@GetMapping("/testSend")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public String testSend() {
    return "testSend";
}
```

I know I am subscribed to the above, because stomp.js says the below in firebug when connected:

```
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/messages
```

Other code I have:

A .ts file I have has this (note the subscribe never seems to trigger):

```
connect() {
        const socket = new SockJS('/api/websocket/chat');
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        this.stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
            // subscribe to the topic
            this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', (messageOutput) => {
                console.log(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
            });
        });
    }
```

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) { 
registry.addEndpoint("/api/websocket/chat")
.setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

---

If you want more information ... the example I linked does have a way in which you can type in a username and message, and send it to the server (who will then send it back to all clients).

The .ts code that sends the message is:

```
sendMessage() {
    const from = $('#from').val();
    const text = $('#text').val();

    const msgBody = JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text});
    this.stompClient.send(
        '/app/chat', {}, msgBody);
}
```

And the REST service looks like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay

    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
}
```

But the problem with that is when I click the "send" button it says `POST http://localhost:9001/api/websocket/chat/703/dvyy2lak/xhr_send?t=1548985676336 404 (Not Found)`

---

Edit: it seems when I try to send a message, I get the below error. So I think this is the issue I'm having

```
2019-02-01 11:09:51 [XNIO-2 task-28] ERROR io.undertow.request - UT005023: Exception handling request to /api/websocket/chat/619/mtgfucnd/xhr_streaming
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:9061/api/websocket/chat/619/mtgfucnd/xhr_streaming?t=1549037391181; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to open session; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to write SockJsFrame content='o'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at com.odp.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:36)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at com.odp.security.idam.IdAMSSOFilter.doFilter(IdAMSSOFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:332)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:9061/api/websocket/chat/619/mtgfucnd/xhr_streaming?t=1549037391181; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to open session; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to write SockJsFrame content='o'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:135)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        ... 102 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to open session; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to write SockJsFrame content='o'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:433)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:132)
        ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to write SockJsFrame content='o'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:342)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.StreamingSockJsSession.handleRequestInternal(StreamingSockJsSession.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:214)
        ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:164)
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:607)
        at org.xnio.conduits.AbstractStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractStreamSinkConduit.java:51)
        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
        at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2074)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flushInternal(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:488)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:475)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.flushBuffer(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:461)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:215)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:215)
        at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:355)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:325)
        ... 113 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you please show your browser console? so that we can check what exactly the issue is. Maybe SockJS is not available on the client side.

Comment: There is no message mapping found for this endpoint ```api/websocket/chat/703/dvyy2lak/xhr_send``` , message mapping has only till ```"/api/websocket/chat"```. you need to handle it appropriately.

Comment: This also helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250719/how-to-send-message-to-client-through-websocket-using-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a STOMP endpoint is configured, the Spring application acts as the STOMP broker to connected clients.

We cannot send the messages to the stomp endpoint as described in the question. 
We need to send the messages to the destination topics `/app/chat`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/websocket/chat")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var stompClient = null;
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/api/websocket/chat');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {

        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (data) {
            console.log("subscription is called");
            console.log("data"+JSON.stringify(data));
        });
        console.log("sending message");
        var msgBody = JSON.stringify({'from':'barath', 'text':'demo'});
        stompClient.send('/app/chat', {}, msgBody);
    });
}

$(function () {
    connect();
});
```

**Output**:

```
mess GenericMessage [payload=byte[31], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chat], content-length=[31]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpHeartbeat=[J@298ce739, lookupDestination=/chat, simpSessionId=w04igwlv, simpDestination=/app/chat}]
mess GenericMessage [payload=byte[31], headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={destination=[/app/chat], content-length=[31]}, simpSessionAttributes={
```

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/issue-54471933-websocket)

Comment: I'm looking at my code and your code, and they seem the same. what is different?

Comment: You are posting the message to the wrong endpoint. That&#39;s the issue. Take a look at the 404 not found endpoint

Comment: on what line of code is that though - we both have: stompClient.send('/app/chat', {}, msgBody);

Comment: You didn't share the code on click of send you are posting something . Share your full code to find out

Comment: Heres the code: this.stompClient.send('/app/chat',{}, msgBody); --- but regardless the main thing I'm trying to do is from my Java code... be able to send a message to a client. I don't care much about a client sending message to server (and server then sending that to client). I care more about my java code with the "SendTo" not working

Comment: Send to /topic/messages is also working. It should work or share your sample in GitHub repo

Comment: I edited it to actually show some error I'm getting in the Java logs, when I try sending a message. i think this is the issue I'm having --- Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to open session; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to write SockJsFrame content='o'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Comment: request pointed to endpoint is not right. share your code in github to find the issue